# Ruby - Configuring alternate DNS for Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

We heavily pound Redis with our infrastructure (approx. 8K requests a sec). Especially because Redis is our job messaging system as well (we use Sidekiq).

Now, many times we get the following errors:

```
RuntimeError: Name or service not known
RuntimeError: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Our Redis configuration is simple:

```
$redis_config = {
    host: ENV['REDIS_HOST'],
    password: ENV['REDIS_PASSWORD'],
    port: 6379,
    driver: :hiredis
}

$redis = Redis.new($redis_config)
```

Im guessing this issue is due to the fact the DNS of our Redis isn't resolving to an IP. So I was thinking about potentially trying an alternate DNS (I have another one) in-case of failure.

Is  there any way I can configure something like that using the Redis Gem?

Comment: Have you tried ruling out dns by using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a bit more clear (also updated the question). Our DNS is sitting at a remote location and its IP is not static (otherwise we would have used IP)